# How to create a slide down and up notification indicator in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation

How to create a slide down and up notification indicator in react native see below for and example

[image]

I would like the notification to slide down for about 3 seconds at the top of the screen and slide up back off the screen after 3 seconds

I tried this below but it is not working

```
const [stateAnimate, setAnimate] = useState(new Animated.Value(300));

  const slideDown = () => {
    Animated.spring(stateAnimate, {
      toValue: 0,
    }).start();

    slideUp();
  };

  const slideUp = setTimeout(() => {
    Animated.spring(stateAnimate, {
      toValue: 0,
    }).start();
    clearTimeout(slideUp);
  }, 3000);


<View>
     <Animated.View style={[{ position: 'absolute', right: 0,left:0,backgroundColor: '#0400ff', height: '20%', width: '100%', }, { transform: [{ translateX: stateAnimate }] }]}>
         <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, color: '#fff', alignSelf: 'center',marginTop:10 }}>loading please wait...</Text>
     </Animated.View>

      <View style={{ marginTop: 200 }}>
        <Button
          title="Slide"
          onPress={() => {
            slideDown();
          }}
        />
      </View>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a Toast like this in my app.

Toast.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, SafeAreaView, FlatList, TextInput, ScrollView, View, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import SafeArea, { type SafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area'

export default class Toast extends React.Component {

    singletonInstance = null;

    state = {
        visible:            false,
        title:              "",
        description:        "",
        backgroundColor:    "",
        textColor:          ""
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        Toast.singletonInstance = this;
        this._isMounted = true;

        SafeArea.getSafeAreaInsetsForRootView().then((result) => {
            this.setState({safeInsetTop: result.safeAreaInsets.top});
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
        this.setState = (state,callback)=>{
            return;
        };
    }

    static show(title, description, backgroundColor, textColor) {
            Toast.singletonInstance._openPanel(title, description, backgroundColor, textColor);
    }


    _openPanel(title, description, backgroundColor, textColor) {

        if (this._isMounted) {
            this.setState({
                visible:            true,
                title:              title,
                description:        description,
                backgroundColor:    backgroundColor,
                textColor:          textColor
            });
            this.setCloseTimer()
        } else {
            this._isMounted = true;
        }
    };


    close = () => {
        if (this._isMounted) {
            if (this.view != null) {
                this.view.fadeOutUp().then(endState =>
                    this.setState({visible: false})
                );
            } else {
                this.setState({visible: false})
            }
        }
    };



    setCloseTimer() {
        this.closeTimer = setTimeout(() => {
               this.close()
        }, 4000);
    }


    handleViewRef = ref => this.view = ref;


    render() {
        if (this.state.visible) {
            return (
                <View style={{width: '100%',  position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0}}>
                    <Animatable.View ref={this.handleViewRef} animation="slideInDown" style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: this.state.safeInsetTop, paddingHorizontal: 20, paddingBottom: 20, backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor}} >
                        <Text ellipsizeMode='tail' numberOfLines={1} style={{fontFamily: "Nunito-ExtraBold", fontSize: 12,  width: '100%', marginLeft: 6, marginTop: 4, color: this.state.textColor}}>{this.state.title}</Text>
                        <Text ellipsizeMode='tail' style={{fontFamily: "Nunito-Bold", fontSize: 18,  width: '100%', marginLeft: 6, marginTop: 4, color: this.state.textColor}}>{this.state.description}</Text>
                    </Animatable.View>
                </View>
            )
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I use it in my other files like this:

```
...
import Toast from '../components/Toast.js'
...
...
Toast.show("Warning!", "You are about to delete everything", "white", "red");
...
```

I'm sure there is a prettier solution or a module somewhere, but it works for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use react-native-paper

[Banner- React Native Paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/banner.html)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Banner } from 'react-native-paper';
const MyComponent = () => {

  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(true);

return <Banner
      visible={visible}
      actions={[
        {
          label: 'Fix it',
          onPress: () => setVisible(false),
        },
        {
          label: 'Learn more',
          onPress: () => setVisible(false),
        },
      ]}
      icon={({size}) => (
        <Image
          source={{
            uri: 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/17571969?s=400&v=4',
          }}
          style={{
            width: size,
            height: size,
          }}
        />
      )}>
      There was a problem processing a transaction on your credit card.
    </Banner>


}
```